# Around annotion executed twice using WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm facing a weird behaviour while using AOP with AspectJ.

Basically the @Around method its called either once either twice and while trying to debugging I can't find the reason why it's being executing twice (I mean what triggers the second execution of the method)

here is some code :

```java
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class ReactiveRedisCacheAspect {
  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.xxx.xxx.cache.aop.annotations.ReactiveRedisCacheable)")
  public void cacheablePointCut() {}
      
  @Around("cacheablePointCut()")
  public Object cacheableAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
     log.debug("ReactiveRedisCacheAspect cacheableAround.... - {}",  proceedingJoinPoint);
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
    Class<?> returnTypeName = method.getReturnType();
    Duration duration = Duration.ofHours(getDuration(method));
    String redisKey = getKey(method, proceedingJoinPoint);

    if (returnTypeName.isAssignableFrom(Flux.class)) {
        log.debug("returning Flux");
        return cacheRepository.hasKey(redisKey)
                .filter(found -> found)
                .flatMapMany(found -> cacheRepository.findByKey(redisKey))
                .flatMap(found -> saveFlux(proceedingJoinPoint, redisKey, duration));
    } else if (returnTypeName.isAssignableFrom(Mono.class)) {
        log.debug("Returning Mono");
        return cacheRepository.hasKey(redisKey)
                .flatMap(found -> {
                    if (found) {
                        return cacheRepository.findByKey(redisKey);
                    } else {
                        return saveMono(proceedingJoinPoint, redisKey, duration);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("non reactive object supported (Mono,Flux)");
    }
  }

 private String getKey(final Method method, final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
        ReactiveRedisCacheable annotation = method.getAnnotation(ReactiveRedisCacheable.class);
        String cacheName = annotation.cacheName();
        String key = annotation.key();
        cacheName = (String) AspectSupportUtils.getKeyValue(proceedingJoinPoint, cacheName);
        key = (String) AspectSupportUtils.getKeyValue(proceedingJoinPoint, key);
        return cacheName + "_" + key;
    }

}
```

```java
public class AspectSupportUtils {

    private static final ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluator();

    public static Object getKeyValue(JoinPoint joinPoint, String keyExpression) {
        if (keyExpression.contains("#") || keyExpression.contains("'")) {
            return getKeyValue(joinPoint.getTarget(), joinPoint.getArgs(), joinPoint.getTarget().getClass(),
                    ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod(), keyExpression);
        }
        return keyExpression;
    }

    private static Object getKeyValue(Object object, Object[] args, Class<?> clazz, Method method, String keyExpression) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(keyExpression)) {
            EvaluationContext evaluationContext = evaluator.createEvaluationContext(object, clazz, method, args);
            AnnotatedElementKey methodKey = new AnnotatedElementKey(method, clazz);
            return evaluator.key(keyExpression, methodKey, evaluationContext);
        }
        return SimpleKeyGenerator.generateKey(args);
    }
}
```

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ReactiveRedisCacheable {
  String key();
  String cacheName();
  long duration() default 1L;
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/pub/v1")
public class TestRestController{

@ReactiveRedisCacheable(cacheName = "test-cache", key = "#name", duration = 1L)
    @GetMapping(value = "test")
    public Mono<String> getName(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name){
        return Mono.just(name);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
   @Bean
    public ReactiveRedisCacheAspect reactiveRedisCache (ReactiveRedisCacheAspect reactiveRedisCacheAspect) {
        return reactiveRedisCacheAspect;
    }
}
```

logs:

```
ReactiveRedisCacheAspect cacheableAround.... - {}execution(Mono com.abc.def.xxx.rest.TestRestcontroller.getName(String))
2021-06-04 15:36:23.096  INFO [fo-bff,f688025287be7e7c,f688025287be7e7c] 20060 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.m.s.c.a.i.ReactiveRedisCacheAspect     : Returning Mono
2021-06-04 15:36:23.097  INFO [fo-bff,f688025287be7e7c,f688025287be7e7c] 20060 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.m.s.c.repository.CacheRepositoryImpl   : searching key: (bff_pippo)
ReactiveRedisCacheAspect cacheableAround.... - {}execution(Mono com.abc.def.xxx.rest.TestRestcontroller.getName(String))
2021-06-04 15:36:23.236  INFO [fo-bff,f688025287be7e7c,f688025287be7e7c] 20060 --- [ioEventLoop-7-2] c.m.s.c.a.i.ReactiveRedisCacheAspect     : Returning Mono
2021-06-04 15:36:23.236  INFO [fo-bff,f688025287be7e7c,f688025287be7e7c] 20060 --- [ioEventLoop-7-2] c.m.s.c.repository.CacheRepositoryImpl   : searching key: (bff_pippo)
2021-06-04 15:36:23.250  INFO [fo-bff,f688025287be7e7c,f688025287be7e7c] 20060 --- [ioEventLoop-7-2] c.m.s.c.repository.CacheRepositoryImpl   : saving obj: (key:bff_pippo) (expiresIn:3600s)
2021-06-04 15:36:23.275  INFO [fo-bff,f688025287be7e7c,f688025287be7e7c] 20060 --- [ioEventLoop-7-2] c.m.s.c.repository.CacheRepositoryImpl   : saving obj: (key:bff_pippo) (expiresIn:3600s)
```

So far I would have expected the cacheableAround would be executed only once, but what happens its a bit weird, if the object is present on redis the method is executed only once but if is not present the method is executed twice which it doesn't make sense, moreover it should be the business logic to manage what to do inside the method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A reproducible test case with complete code would help avoid a lot of guess work . What happens when the object is not present in cache ? I assume it would attempt a fallback which satisfies the pointcut expression.

Comment: the behaviour is very simple, If the object is present in cache return it else save it. As I said before that is part of the business logic and it shouldn't concern the "caller". There is not a fallback since everything is incapsulated in the method. I've been lookinf a bit at the source code and more or less cache annotation does the same what it actually surprise me and mostly confuse me if that the method it's triggered twice and it's not a perception but a real fact, moreover the I can see that the same saving operation is done twice on Redis while the find operation only once.

Comment: Unable to comprehend based on your comment. It would be great if you can share a reproducible testcase or something. There are many experts here who can help if there is something for them to debug and resolve the issue.

Comment: Something should trigger the target method call twice , which results in the unexpected advice. Did you try setting a breakpoint at the advice method and check the call stack to verify the behaviour ?

Comment: there is a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and that scaried me even more because even debuggin I can't come a head :(

Comment: @R.G I've just updated the topic, now you can find all the classes (I made)involved in the process.

Comment: the code is incomplete . could you please share what is `getKey(method, proceedingJoinPoint)` doing ? Please check the code completeness before sharing

Comment: If the first execution is at `2021-06-04 15:36:23.096` and the second unexpected execution is at `2021-06-04 15:36:23.236` , the log clearly shows that `TestRestcontroller.getName(String))` is getting called twice. You should investigate why that happens. If not sure , please share the code which results in the `TestRestcontroller.getName(String))` controller method call.

Comment: I think I found the problem. It should be the reactive pipeline behind it, it tried to simplify the operation and it kind of works. Honestly I was against of using aop in this reactive application, since I've already created all the cache logic inside the most services but you know, the boss is the boss.

Comment: AOP is not the problem. Your boss is not the problem. I am supporting his idea to maintain the logic for this cross-cutting concern centrally, instead of scattering and repeating it in all existing and future services, which would be a maintenance nightmare. AOP is not difficult, if you work with it for a while. It is only difficult at first, like every new paradigm. _“It may seem difficult at first, but all things are difficult at first.” Miyamoto Musashi, The Book of Five Rings_

Comment: Totally agree. My point is pretty simple, I'm not against new technologies, frameworks or paradigms mostly I'm the happiest person if I have to learn something new. In this case, I would like to keep the whole application "full reactive" with all its components.(aop is not reactive actually it a blocking part that I wanted to avoid but I know sometimes we should find a compromise and probably this is right time for it.) Btw thank you for the advice and thank you to everyone that helped me in this thread 

Comment: Did you solved it @maxuel ?
Im having similar (double execution) issue after  springboot upgrade (2.3 from  1.5). Was thinking maybe they are related somehow..

Comment: @my- not really. I've tried to investigate a bit deeper and I've noticed that the double execution is related to the mono. Try no to use a mono but just a regular object and you will notice that I will be executed correctly only once.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether you use native AspectJ via load- or compile-time weaving or simply Spring AOP. Because I see not `@Component` annotation on your aspect, it might as well be native AspectJ, unless you configure your beans via `@Bean` factory methods in a configuration class or XML.

Assuming that you are using full AspectJ, a common problem newbies coming from Spring AOP have, is that they are not used to the fact that AspectJ not only intercepts `execution` joinpoints, but also `call` ones. This leads to the superficial perception that the same joinpoint is intercepted twice. But in reality, it is once the method call (in the class from which the call is made) and once the method execution (in the class where the target method resides). This is easy to determine if at the beginning of your advice method you simply log the joinpoint. In your case:

```java
System.out.println(proceedingJoinPoint);
```

If then on the console you see something like

```
call(public void org.acme.MyClass.myMethod())
execution(public void org.acme.MyClass.myMethod())
```

then you know what is happening.

In case you use Spring AOP, probably it is an issue with the aspect or the Redis caching behaviour that is different from your expectation.

Comment: The aspect is annotated via @Bean in the configuration class. Looking at the monitor on Redis I can properly see the two "set" request whenever I have to save and only one "get" request if the object is already present in cache, hence I don't think it's a perception but a proper fact. Also looking at the debug I can see that in one case a current state variable is set to 1 and that is when the object is in cache and if not the same variable is set to 2 (in this case the method is executed twice).

Comment: It is nice for you, that **you** can see all this. I can see nothing of it, and your sample code does not constitute an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So like R.G already said: Please provide one. Your explanations are not testable or debuggable. If you want help here, make sure to enable others to actually help you. Nobody wants to guess and speculate based on incomplete facts here. I am already beginning to regret that I did.

Comment: I apologize for the previous answer. I'm about to upload more specific information which could provide a wider point of view of the issue I'm facing. Thank you for helping!